# Send message to Facebook user using user Id with API in C#

Tags: c#, facebook, api, sendmessage

We need to send message to Facebook User from our Facebook page which we have created using Facebook

-We have checked with Graph API and webhook subscription but for that it requires recipientId (PSID) but this PSID is not same as user Id. So we can not follow that method.(Reference Link: https://tutorials.botsfloor.com/facebook-chatbot-in-asp-net-2f9379a238b0)

We have created some test users in Facebook developer account and we need to implement sending message functionality for the same.

Comment: what user id? how did you get the user id? are you aware that you can only reply to message, not initiate them? it would be weird if you could just send message to a user without him authorizing it first (by sending a message). it would be called spam ;)

Comment: You can not just message any arbitrary user, that would be spam. Whether you can message them in this case, depends on the specifics ... but you didn’t really give any. A message bot to answer when they send your page a message would be one option, private comment replies another.